# Common Lisp lambda expression error

Tags: syntax-error, common-lisp

I am trying to make a program, which will rewrite given row without duplicates in an output row. I am using this website as a compiler:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lisp_online.php

And here is my code

```
(SETQ X (LIST  2 -3 (LIST 4 3 0 2) (LIST 4 -4) (LIST 2 (LIST 2 0 2))-3))'
(DEFUN SEARCHDEEP (WHAT WHERE) ;Function will find out if atom `WHAT`is in a row `WHERE` => works fine
(COND
    ((NULL WHERE) NIL)
    (T (OR 
            (COND 
                ((ATOM (CAR WHERE)) (EQUAL WHAT (CAR WHERE)))
                (T (SEARCHDEEP WHAT  (CAR WHERE)))
            )
            (SEARCHDEEP WHAT (CDR WHERE))
        )
    )
)
)

(DEFUN REMDOUBLES (INPUT OUTPUT)
(
(COND 
    ((NULL INPUT) NILL) ;recursion exit
    (T                  ; funstion
        (OR             ; step into or go forward
            (COND 
                ((ATOM (CAR INPUT)) (COND 
                                        ((NOT (SEARCHDEEP (CAR INPUT) OUTPUT)) (APPEND OUTPUT INPUT)) ;if this atom wasn't added => append
                                    )
                )
                (T (REMDOUBLES (CAR INPUT) OUTPUT)) ; step into (car input => list
            )
            (REMDOUBLES (CRD INPUT) OUTPUT) ; go forward, car input is anatom
        )
    )
)
)
)

(SETQ OUT (QUOTE)) ;Empty row
(REMDOUBLES X OUT)
(PRINT OUT)
```

I have spent last 2 hours checking this code and other answers here, on stack, however I have no clue what am I missing here.

I am getting this error:

`*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM:

(COND ((NULL INPUT) NILL)(T(OR (COND ((ATOM (CAR INPUT)) (COND ((NOT (SEARCHDEEP (CAR INPUT) OUTPUT))(APPEND OUTPUT INPUT)))) (T (REMDOUBLES (CAR INPUT) OUTPUT))) (REMDOUBLES (CRD INPUT) OUTPUT)))) should be a lambda expression`

Sorry for the formatting,  I am novice in Functional Programming and Lisp, and I have no idea how it should be done properly.

Comment: You have an extra opening parenthesis between `(DEFUN REMDOUBLES (INPUT OUTPUT)` and `(COND`. Indent your code correctly! Any semi-decent editor will indent it for you.

Comment: There is also an error in th line `((NULL INPUT) NILL)`, which should be `((NULL INPUT) NIL)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your code:**

First line:

```
(DEFUN REMDOUBLES (INPUT OUTPUT)
```

Second line: **Can you explain what the single parentheses should do?**

```
(
```

You remember the Lisp syntax for basic Lisp expressions?

```
(operator argument0 argument1 ... argumentn)
```

It's not

```
((operator argument0 argument1 ... argumentn))
```

> Sorry for the formatting, i am novice in functional programming and LISP, and i have no idea how it should be done properly.

Download the introductory Lisp book from Touretzky: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Then learn there how Lisp code looks like.

You can also use Lisp to format the code for you:

This is your unformatted code:

```
[4]> (pprint '(DEFUN SEARCHDEEP (WHAT WHERE) ;Function will find out if atom `WHAT`is in a row `WHERE` => works fine
(COND
    ((NULL WHERE) NIL)
    (T (OR 
            (COND 
                ((ATOM (CAR WHERE)) (EQUAL WHAT (CAR WHERE)))
                (T (SEARCHDEEP WHAT  (CAR WHERE)))
            )
            (SEARCHDEEP WHAT (CDR WHERE))
        )
    )
)
))
```

This is the formatted code:

```
(DEFUN SEARCHDEEP (WHAT WHERE)
 (COND ((NULL WHERE) NIL)
  (T
   (OR
    (COND ((ATOM (CAR WHERE)) (EQUAL WHAT (CAR WHERE)))
     (T (SEARCHDEEP WHAT (CAR WHERE))))
    (SEARCHDEEP WHAT (CDR WHERE))))))
```

But it would be even better written as:

```
(DEFUN SEARCHDEEP (WHAT WHERE)
  (WHEN WHERE
    (OR (IF (ATOM (CAR WHERE))
            (EQUAL WHAT (CAR WHERE))
          (SEARCHDEEP WHAT (CAR WHERE)))
        (SEARCHDEEP WHAT (CDR WHERE)))))
```