# Common lisp workin with list

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp

my task is to count all element within a list, which have duplicates, eg
( 2 2 (3 3) 4 (3)) will result in 2 (because only 2 and 3 have duplicates)
Searchdeep - just returns a nill if `WHAT` isn't find in list `WHERE`
Count2 - go through the single elements and sub-lists

If it finds atom he will use `SEARCHDEEP` to figure out does it have duplicates, then list `OUT` will be checked (to make sure if this atom was not already counted (e.g. like ( 3 3 3), which should return 1, not 2)
, increase counter and add atom to the `OUT` list.

However, i don't understand why, but it constantly returns only 1. I think it is some kind of logical mistake or wrong use of function.

My code is:

```
(SETQ OUT NIL)
(SETQ X (LIST  2 -3 (LIST 4 3 0 2) (LIST 4 -4) (LIST 2 (LIST 2 0 2))-5)) 
(SETQ count 0)
(DEFUN SEARCHDEEP (WHAT WHERE)    (COND
    ((NULL WHERE) NIL)
    (T (OR 
            (COND 
                ((ATOM (CAR WHERE)) (EQUAL WHAT (CAR WHERE)))
                (T (SEARCHDEEP WHAT  (CAR WHERE)))
            )
            (SEARCHDEEP WHAT (CDR WHERE))
        )
    )
)
)
(DEFUN Count2 ( input) 
(print input)
(COND
    ((NULL input) NIL)
    (T  
        (or
            (COND 
                ((ATOM (CAR input)) 
                            (COND 
                                (
                                    (and ;if
                                        (SEARCHDEEP (CAR INPUT) (CDR INPUT))
                                        (NOT (SEARCHDEEP (CAR INPUT) OUT))
                                    ) 
                                    (and ;do
                                        (Setq Count (+ count 1)) 
                                        (SETQ OUT (append OUT (LIST (CAR INPUT))))
                                        (Count2 (CDR input))
                                    )
                                )
                                (t (Count2 (CDR input)))
                            )
                )
                (T (Count2 (CAR input)))
            )
            (Count2 (CDR input))
        )
    )
)
)
(Count2 x)
(print count)
```

Comment: Looks like you have asked similar questions before under a different user name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808344/functional-programming-in-lisp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811497/common-lisp-lambda-expression-error   Unfortunately your programming style has not improved and the code is not readable. :-(

Answer (score 3):

First, your code has some big style issues. Don't write in uppercase (some, like myself, like to write symbols in uppercase in comments and in text outside of code, but the code itself should be written in lowercase), and don't put parentheses on their own lines. So the `SEARCHDEEP` function should look more like

```
(defun search-deep (what where)
  (cond ((null where) nil)
        (t (or (cond ((atom (car where)) (equal what (car where)))
                     (t (searchdeep what (car where))))
               (searchdeep what (cdr where))))))
```

You also should not use `SETQ` to define variables. Use `DEFPARAMETER` or `DEFVAR` instead, although in this case you should not use global variables in the first place. You should name global variables with asterisks around the name (`*X*` instead of `x`, but use a more descriptive name).

For the problem itself, I would start by writing a function to traverse a tree.

```
(defun traverse-tree (function tree)
  "Traverse TREE, calling FUNCTION on every atom."
  (typecase tree
    (atom (funcall function tree))
    (list (dolist (item tree)
            (traverse-tree function item))))
  (values))
```

Notice that `TYPECASE` is more readable than `COND` in this case. You should also use the mapping or looping constructs provided by the language instead of writing recursive loops yourself. The `(values)` at the end says that the function will not return anything.

```
(let ((tree '(2 -3 (4 3 0 2) (4 -4) (2 (2 0 2)) -5)))
  (traverse-tree (lambda (item)
                   (format t "~a " item))
                 tree))
; 2 -3 4 3 0 2 4 -4 2 2 0 2 -5 
; No values
```

If you were traversing trees a lot, you could hide that function behind a `DO-TREE` macro

```
(defmacro do-tree ((var tree &optional result) &body body)
  `(progn (traverse-tree (lambda (,var)
                           ,@body)
                         ,tree)
          ,result))

(let ((tree '(2 -3 (4 3 0 2) (4 -4) (2 (2 0 2)) -5)))
  (do-tree (item tree)
    (format t "~a " item)))
; 2 -3 4 3 0 2 4 -4 2 2 0 2 -5 
;=> NIL
```

Using this, we can write a function that counts every element in the tree, returning an alist. I'll use a hash table to keep track of the counts. If you're only interested in counting numbers that will stay in a small range, you might want to use a vector instead.

```
(defun tree-count-elements (tree &key (test 'eql))
  "Count each item in TREE. Returns an alist in 
form ((item1 . count1) ... (itemn . countn))"
  (let ((table (make-hash-table :test test)))
    (do-tree (item tree)
      (incf (gethash item table 0)))
    (loop for value being the hash-value in table using (hash-key key)
          collect (cons key value))))

(let ((tree '(2 -3 (4 3 0 2) (4 -4) (2 (2 0 2)) -5)))
  (tree-count-elements tree))
;=> ((2 . 5) (-3 . 1) (4 . 2) (3 . 1) (0 . 2) (-4 . 1) (-5 . 1))
```

The function takes a keyword argument for the `TEST` to use with the hash table. For numbers or characters, `EQL` works.

Now you can use the standard `COUNT-IF`-function to count the elements that occur more than once.

```
(let ((tree '(2 -3 (4 3 0 2) (4 -4) (2 (2 0 2)) -5)))
  (count-if (lambda (item)
              (> item 1))
            (tree-count-elements tree)
            :key #'cdr))
;=> 3
```

Comment: The problem is, i have to use functions provided by my professor, almost all of them are mentioned in my code, so i cant use your code.

Comment: @rainbowShiningUnicorn You should add that to your question (with a list of allowed functions).